# File name from attachment via mail mime php

Tags: php, email, mime

I'm having a problem using long file names in attachment send by mime mail.

When I use shortnames, like: `rapport.pdf` it works fine.

But when I start using long file names like: `rapport_2013_rapport_2013_rapport_2013_rapport_2013_rapport_2013_.pdf` the file gets a new name when sending the file to the e-mail (untiteled attchment `xxxxx.pdf`).

Is there a way to fix this? I already tried to change the encode to inline or attachments.
This is the code i use:

```
 $mime = new Mail_Mime();
 $mime->setHtmlBody($htmlMessage);
 $mime->addAttachment($pdfcontent, 'application/pdf', 'factuur_QW'.$fcnr.'.pdf', false, 'base64');
 $body = $mime->get();
 $hdrs = $mime->headers($headers);
 $mail = &Mail::factory('mail');
 $mail->send($to, $hdrs, $body);
```

Comment: What do you use to send your email? Can we see some code?

Comment: I just added a piece of code.

Comment: I've also found problems with accented characters. My bet is to keep file names under 64 characters non-accented

Answer (score 0):

I came across this article: [Is there any limit on the maximum length of filename while sending attachments?](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3773901)

This suggests that you can have longer filenames if they are encoded appropriately.  Try:

```
$mime->addAttachment($pdfcontent, 'application/pdf', 'factuur_QW'.$fcnr.'.pdf', false, 'base64', 'attachment', '', '', '', 'encoded-word', null, '=?utf-8?B' . base64_encode('factuur_QW'.$fcnr') . '?=', null);
```

Based on the mime type specified, '.pdf' will be added to the attachment filename. There is also no need to encode the attachment name using base64 if the characters are in the Ascii character set.  In this case, replace '=utf-8?B?' with '=utf-8?Q?'.